# Why doesn't search find my answer?

Tags: support, answers, search, formatting

To give [Bond eth0 and LTE Modem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363084/bond-eth0-and-lte-modem) a pointer, I was trying to find a previous answer I knew I'd written about how we use multiple ISPs at work. I was also going to point to some other folk's answers, but first of course I had to find them. Policy routing on Linux is done with the `ip` command's `rule` subcommand. So the answers should all include `ip rule`, but searching for that didn't really find any. I know I have written one, so I searched:

> ["ip rule" is:a user:977](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ip+rule%22+is%3Aa+user%3A977)
>       → 0 results.

Errr, I managed to find my answer eventually: [Routing for multiple uplinks/providers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70440/routing-for-multiple-uplinks-providers/71834#71834) and note the line `Maginot:~# ip rule ls` — "ip rule" is right there!

If I search for just "rule" instead, it finds it.

All I can figure is that search is ignoring code blocks. Ugh. Presuming that's the case, is there some trick (other than the obvious, [why did you bother with a search other than Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22derobert%22+%22ip+rule%22+site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com&ie=UTF-8)) to get search to search inside code blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does seem like search just ignores code blocks; I can't find any mention of if this is intentional, it seems like an odd decision, and the [meta thread about the new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) implies that it should work:

> - Quoted phrases are ***exact*** matches except for case-sensitivity, for example, [you can search for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q="COUNT%28*%29+AS+UpVotes") or [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22*=%22).

---

There is a way to search *only* code blocks, the entirely undocumented `code:` filter, so [`code:"ip rule" is:a user:997`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22ip+rule%22+is%3Aa+user%3A977) will work. Note that that wouldn't find answers where you mentioned "ip rule" outside a code block; I think you'd have to run two separate searches to cover both cases.

Comment: Well, this explains why I found nothing relevant while searching for `rm "cannot remove" "is a directory"`, but after I posted [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436918/108618) it turned out to be a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29769/108618). My original search *should* have found the other question and prevent me from posting a duplicate.